# how to play multiple audio with js audio api

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm reading audio files from the server. And I have an array for raw audio files.

```
const allAudio = [];
```

Then I play them sequentially.

```
var volumeSeq=1;

    function playAudio(){
     if(volumeSeq==allAudio.length){ volumeSeq=1;}
      var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
      source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
      audioCtx.decodeAudioData(allAudio[volumeSeq], function(buffer) {
      source.buffer = buffer;
      console.log(source.buffer);
      source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      source.loop = false;});

      source.start(0);
      source.onended = function () {
        volumeSeq++;
        playAudio();
}
```

I catch the problem. But I don't know why. Problem is, that after the decoding i.element of the array, the element in it is being deleted. I mean when I decode the allAudio[1] then allAudio[1] is empty.
So I cant create a loop for these audio tracks.

What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you decode all audio files at the begining, and then loop through them? Like this:

```
var allAudio = [];
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var volumeSeq = 0;
var decodedAudio = [];

function decodeAudio() {
    allAudio.forEach(function (file, index) {
        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(file, function(buffer) {
            decodedAudio[index] = buffer;
            if (decodedAudio.length >= allAudio.length) {
                play();
            }
        })
     })
}
function play() {
    if (volumeSeq >= allAudio.length){ volumeSeq=0;}
    var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = decodedAudio[volumeSeq];
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.start(0);
    source.onended = function () {
        volumeSeq++;
        play();
    }
}
decodeAudio();
```

Few more things:

- You don't need to create [`AudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/AudioContext) every time.
- [`AudioBufferSourceNode.loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/loop) is false by default. You can skip `source.loop = false;`
- Every new variable should start with `const`, `let` or `var`. You are missing it with `source`. BTW nowadays it is beter to use `const` and `let`, not `var`. I will show it in next "modern" example.
- I don't know why you iterate `allAudio` starting from index 1. First index in array is 0.

If you don't care about old browsers like IE, you can make code cleaner by using [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and `async/await`:

```
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
async function start() {
   const decodedAudio = await Promise.all(allAudio.map((file) => audioCtx.decodeAudioData(file)));
   let volumeSeq = 0;
   function play() {
        if(volumeSeq >= allAudio.length) volumeSeq = 0;
        const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = decodedAudio[volumeSeq];
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        source.start(0);
        source.addEventListener('ended', () => {
           volumeSeq++;
           play();
        }, { once: true })
   }
   play();
}
start()
```